# MariaDB Table Creation Error with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb, mysql-workbench

There are many questions like that but I cannot find my answer among them.

Can you tell me what is wrong here? The script was created by mysql Workbench but it does not except the answer

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Mon Nov 26 14:14:46 2018
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;    
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,     SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Owner`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Owner` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Owner` (
  `OwnerId` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `Name` NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Adress` NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OwnerId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Account`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Account` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Account` (
  `AccountId` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `DateCreated` DATE NOT NULL,
  `AccountType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `OwnerId` CHAR(36) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccountId`),
  INDEX `fk_Account_Owner_idx` (`OwnerId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Account_Owner`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OwnerId`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Owner` (`OwnerId`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

The given error is

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual
>       that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
>       near '   CONSTRAINT `fk_Account_Owner`     FOREIGN KEY (`OwnerId`)
>       REFERENCES `myd' at line 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench and phpMyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915347/mysql-workbench-and-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Also, duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52785302/2469308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785125/mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another case of needing to get rid of the word `VISIBLE`.

Comment: but the workbench created that script isn't it supposed to be correct ??
I am trying what you wrote now.

Comment: Actually, it's not the VISIBLE keyword, which is the true culprit, but the server version which is set for modeling (see model preferences).

Comment: @Johnyy66554 - Workbench is built by Oracle, and the latest version is aimed for the latest version of MySQL (8.0), which has a _new_ keyword `VISIBLE`.  Since Workbench seems to want to aggressively include that word, it causes errors in _all_ older versions of MySQL, and all versions of MariaDB.  This forum is being littered with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Workbench:

Go to:

Edit > Preferences > Modeling > MySQL.

Then, set the "Default Target MySQL Version" to 5.7

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52785302/2625955

Comment: Tried that but did not help. Still exactly the same problem.