# why does mariadb gives a syntax error for a sql file created with workbench

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have created a model with mysql workbench and every time I want to execute the sql file given i get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 55 in file: 'D:\db.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>     CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_order_customer1`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
>       ' at line 8
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 76 in file: 'D:\db.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>     CONSTRAINT `fk_product_category`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
>       REFERENC' at line 9
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 98 in file: 'D:\db.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>     INDEX `fk_ordered_product_product` (`customer_order_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
>     CONST' at line 6

and this is the code mysql workbench generated for me

```
  -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ecommerce_ee
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `ecommerce_ee` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ecommerce_ee
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ecommerce_ee` ;
USE `ecommerce_ee` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ecommerce_ee`.`customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`customer` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`customer` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `city_region` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cc_number` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ecommerce_ee`.`category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`category` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`category` (
  `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ecommerce_ee`.`customer_order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`customer_order` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`customer_order` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `confirmation_number` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_customer_order_customer` (`customer_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_order_customer1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
    REFERENCES `ecommerce_ee`.`customer` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ecommerce_ee`.`product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`product` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`product` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `description` TINYTEXT NULL,
  `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `category_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `name`),
  INDEX `fk_product_category` (`category_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
    REFERENCES `ecommerce_ee`.`category` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ecommerce_ee`.`ordered_product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`ordered_product` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ecommerce_ee`.`ordered_product` (
  `customer_order_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_order_id`, `product_id`),
  INDEX `fk_ordered_product_customer_order` (`product_id` ASC, `quantity` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ordered_product_product` (`customer_order_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_order_has_product_customer_order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_order_id`)
    REFERENCES `ecommerce_ee`.`customer_order` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_order_has_product_product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id` , `quantity`)
    REFERENCES `ecommerce_ee`.`product` (`id` , `name`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: duplicate of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480613/mariadb-table-creation-error-with-foreign-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MariaDB Table Creation Error with Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480613/mariadb-table-creation-error-with-foreign-key)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the keyword `VISIBLE`.  (It was just *before* the 'near' text.)

Comment: Thanks this did work for me the other solutions didn't

Comment: `VISIBLE` is a very new keyword; it is the default.  Workbench seems to be too eager to unnecessarily include it.  It should not do so because it leads to backward incompatibilities, as you found out.