# MySQL workbench data importing, foreign key error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im workin in mySQL workbench 8.0CE, i've created two tables, one for person and another one for persons direction, i'm trying to export data, but it throws and error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 67: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PersonaDireccion`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)
    REFERENCES' at line 8

Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

This is the sql code

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dinSchema`.`Personas` (
  `nombre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoP` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoM` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `foto` MEDIUMBLOB NULL,
  `fechaCaptura` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  `escolaridad` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `carrera` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `correo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `rfc` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  `curp` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
  `observaciones` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  `idPersonas` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonas`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dinSchema`.`direccion`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dinSchema`.`direccion` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dinSchema`.`direccion` (
  `pais` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'México',
  `estado` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `cp` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `idPersona` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_PersonaDireccion_idx` (`idPersona` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PersonaDireccion`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)
    REFERENCES `dinSchema`.`Personas` (`idPersonas`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

next i append EER Diagram img 
[image: EER Diagram]

Note: "Personas" id field is at last, beacuse i deleted a foreign key connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785125/mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1)

Comment: Also, check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915425/2469308

Comment: I've created those tables as a model in workbench, exported the sql file with Forward engineer SQL Create, then tried to import the sql file with Data Import/Restore -> Import from self contained file

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i fixed it, unchecked user default global settings in model options, and

```
INDEX `fk_PersonaDireccion_idx` (`idPersona` ASC) VISIBLE
```

disapeared, now "direccion" table got like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dinSchema`.`direccion` (
  `pais` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'México',
  `estado` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `cp` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `idPersona` INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PersonaDireccion`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`)
    REFERENCES `dinSchema`.`Personas` (`idPersonas`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```